# How to hide a image button from printing using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a "Print" button in my web page (php html) and I don't want it to print along with my data.
Can I do it with CSS? Is there another way?

Comment: Instead of hiding that button open a new window with javascript with the content you want to print and call the javascript function to print in that window and close it.

Comment: He's asking for the CSS way, not the JS way.

Comment: @JamieHutber I am not sure whether CSS way will work on all browsers. That is why I suggested that option.

Comment: fair enough. css won't work with all browsers.

Comment: I need to pass variables with php so I can't use window.open()

Comment: @CarlosMartins That is not an issue, you can send data via GET in URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can with CSS, although support will only be with browsers that support CSS3.

But its simple:

```
 @media print {
    …
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

assign an id(buttonId) to the button eg: `id="buttonId"`
and then in css:

```
#buttonId
{
    display:none;
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

just use the above css file for the same.

Comment: can you please explain why it is downvoted?

Comment: I think it wont hide the other buttons as id is used and only one element will have that id in the page

Answer (score 1):

Just create multiple style sheets

```
<style type="text/css" media="all"> @import "nucss2.css";</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

And look at the

> media="print"